# Anaconda3 and base environments upon installation of anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, anaconda3

After freshly installing anaconda on my (windows 10) system, I see a base and an Anaconda3 environments.
[image]

I cannot figure out what this Anaconda3 environment is and why it is installed automatically. Should I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a conda environment. You can access it and see what is included with `activate Anaconda3` in the console. You can see what version of python it is by then typing "python" into your console and checkout which packages are installed with `pip freeze`.

Note, that depending on how you reinstalled your anaconda, your old environments can persist. Thus, this could be an environment you previously created as part of a tutorial or something. As long as you are not seeing anything in the above that might mess up your work (such as it having your expected packages / python version) it is safe to delete.